# Alamofire & Codeigniter RESTful Server

Tags: php, swift, rest, codeigniter, alamofire

I am trying to get Alamofire on Swift 3 to send a post request to my Codeigniter based RESTful server (using: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient)

I have got the request working but am struggling to get Alamofire to handle any error messages that is being sent back from my REST server

Swift 3 code

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.0.26/index.php/register/user", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

            print(response.result)

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }

        }
```

In codeigniter im sending an array of errors based on the form validation rules and passing it back like

```
$this->response($error, 404);
```

$error is basically a multiarray like this

```
$error = ["error" => ['field_name' => 'must contain unique value']];
```

But in my debug section on xcode im getting success and struggling to then handle the json result

```
SUCCESS
JSON: (
        {
        error =         {
            "field_email" = "The Email field must contain a unique value.";
        };
    },
        {
        error =         {
            "field_username" = "The Username field must contain a unique value.";
        };
    }
)
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction to basically determine wether the actual result was a success (if it was perform this action) and if not handle the error messages?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a response code 200.